# htaccess help for directory parsing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a newbie to .htaccess / mod_rewrite and have run into a problem..

I have just updated my website to a new Wordpress install, but have my old site running on a separate server.. On the old server, I have 4 names sites running.. I was successful in using multiple rewrite rules above the WordPress rewrite code, until some provides a URL not in my list which then just goes to the new Wordpress site with an item not found post, instead of redirecting..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   "^ONE(.*)$"  "http://old.site.com/ONE/$1"  [R,L,NC]
RewriteRule   "^TWO(.*)$"  "http://old.site.com/TWO/$1"  [R,L,NC]
RewriteRule   "^THREE(.*)$"  "http://old.site.com/THREE/$1"  [R,L,NC]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# www.newsite.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How do I make fix this so that the old sites in the list are redirected, ELSE if the URL such as http://www.oldsite.com/FOUR is redirected to either an Static error page or just to the www.newsite.com..

Thanks in Advance

k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first block you can create another catch-all redirect rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ONE(.*)$ http://old.site.com/ONE/$1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^TWO(.*)$ http://old.site.com/TWO/$1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^THREE(.*)$ http://old.site.com/THREE/$1 [R,L,NC]

# catch-all rule
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/ [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can now even remove all WP rules as those rules will not be even used at this point.